# iMacros "__undefined__" while trying to extract link using match keyword

Tags: var, imacros, mach

I am trying to make this work. Saving links in a .txt file based on a word/keyword match.

here is a code :

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=h3 ATTR=class:r extract=htm
SET resultLink EVAL("var s='{{!EXTRACT}}';var match txt=\mmorpg\")
set !extract {{resultLink}}
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\tmp FILE=GameList.txt
set !extract null
```

But all I get is `"__undefined__"` in GameList.txt

Can someone help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your comment and after looking at http://www.mmorpg.com/gamelist.cfm, the code, probably, must be like this:

```
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !LOOP 1
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=TD ATTR=CLASS:alt EXTRACT=HTM
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/http.*html/)[0];")
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\tmp FILE=GameList.txt
```

Play it in loop mode with the max loop value, say, 841 (the max row of the table with links).

---

Obsolete info:

Try the second line of your macro as follows:

```
SET resultLink EVAL("('{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/mmorpg/)) ? '{{!EXTRACT}}' : 'no match!';")
```

Comment: This is somehow working, but it saves everything from the source. I just want to save only the link ( exemple : http://www.mmorpg.com/gamelist.cfm ) in GameList.txt ! Nothing more, nothing less, just the link. Do you know what should I change ? Thanks!

Comment: this is what it returns in GameList.Txt : `"<h3 style=""outline: 1px solid blue;"" class=""r""><a href=""http://www.mmorpg.com/"" onmousedown=""return rwt(this,'','','','1','AFQjCNFsJhl4Cv-TYyIoxF7cQTmTEEw60w','','0CCEQFjAAahUKEwiivMvS2NvGAhUGK9sKHScjAfY','','',event)"">Free MMORPG List and MMO Games - MMORPG.com</a></h3>"` ! So all I want is only the link to be saved , exemple the one from a href : http://www.mmorpg.com/